# How to initiate cursor position center over placeholder text react native?

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native, textinput

My textinput cursor initially blinking in the starting of the placeholder text. If I remove placeholder text, it is blinking in the correct position[Based on textAlignment]. How to make cursor initial position in the center with placeholder text and text alignment center.

The cursor position should be like this:
[image]

My outpou:

[image]

Code:

```
<TextInput
    selectionColor={'#1688EA'}
    placeholder={"Enter email here"}
    keyboardType="email-address"
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoCompleteType='email'
    autoCorrect={true}
    textAlign="center"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    placeholderTextColor={this.state.hasFocus ? "#C6C6C6" : "#959595"}
    onFocus={this.setFocus.bind(this, true)}
    onBlur={this.setFocus.bind(this, false)}
    numberOfLines={1}
    style={{
        color: "#010101", flex: 1,
        height: 48,
        alignContent: "center",
        fontSize: 17,
        paddingLeft: 28,
        fontFamily: Fonts.GilroySemiBold,
        textAlignVertical: 'center'
    }}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setEmailText(text)}
    value={this.state.email}
    ref={(ref) => { this.email_entry = ref }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `TextInput` supports it. You'll have to make a custom placeholder yourself. The idea is to remove the placeholder `<Text>` element when user inputs something.

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View>
        {/* This is a placeholder, it is positioned behind the actual text input */}
        {/* It is rendered conditionally */}
        {text.length === 0 && (
           <Text style={styles.placeholder}>
             Enter your email here
           </Text>
        )}

        {/* The actual text input */}
        <TextInput />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textInput: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  placeholder: { ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, textAlign: 'center' },
});
```

Here is an expo snack with a proof-of-concept:

https://snack.expo.io/@ivanmoskalev/custom-textinput-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

**Add these styles to the textInput**

```
{
flex:1,
textAlign:"center",
}
```

It will definitely be right
**good luck** my friend